# I have the latest version of grails 3.3.7 but when i check grails -version it still says 2.3.11. On a separate note, I need to upgrade to 2.5.6.

Tags: grails

I have the latest version of grails 3.3.7 but when i check grails -version it still says 2.3.11. On a separate note, I need to upgrade to 2.5.6.

This is what I see: 
Application expects grails version [2.5.6], but GRAILS_HOME is version [2.3.11] - use the correct Grails version or run 'grails upgrade' if this Grails version is newer than the version your application expects.

But when I use brew install grails, I see: grails 3.3.7 is already installed and up-to-date

I am confused, what is the correct version thats on my system now? and how can I get 2.5.6?

Comment: There is a lot of confusion here.  It sounds like you are not distinguishing between which grails versions you have installed (you may very well have many installed) and which your application is written for (just one).  Did you try running "grails upgrade" as suggested?

Answer (score 1):

If `grails --version` reports 2.3.11 that indicates that you have 2.3.11 installed on your system and that it is on your `PATH`.  If you have multiple versions on your `PATH` (there is no good reason to do that), it looks like 2.3.11 is the first one.

You may install as many versions of Grails a you like and have them all installed concurrently.  In order to use a particular version, have your `GRAILS_HOME` environment variable point to the directory where you have that version installed and make sure that `%GRAILS_HOME%\bin` is on your `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed had multiple versions in the PATH and also was using sdkman. Somehow anything installed outside of sdkman wasn't recognized including newer java version. I changed it now and everything is fine.

Comment: You can definitely use stuff that is installed outside of sdkman but in order to do that, you need to make sure your version is configured on the `PATH` in front of whatever version sdkman has configured.  Generally there is no good reason to do that if you are using sdkman, but you can if you have some reason to want to do that.  Really all sdkman is doing (aside from the download management) is moving symlinks around and configuring the PATH.